# How to stop prestashop paypal module replacing logo files with originals?

Tags: paypal, prestashop, chmod

I'm using the paypal module for prestashop and have replaced the default paypal logos with my ones in the module's img dir. However, every few days they somehow get replaced by the original logo files. How can I stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it being auto-updated?

If you are editing the paypal module the safest thing to do would be to copy and rename the module.

If you are only editing the image and don't want to rename it, set the permissions to 644 so the images cannot be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but I guess my answer could help someone. The best solution I have found is to update the logo with your own file and to set the corresponding property in your logos.xml file with the link of your own file saved on your webserver.